# Need to create a query for monthly data

Tags: mysql

I need to create a query in mysql  to retrieve data where  CREATED_DATE range should be 20th of current month to 20th of previous month. Please suggest..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get dynamic records using current month, by the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-20') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
AND DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),'%Y-%m-20')
```

Check the live result at the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4668c/7

Comment: thanks a lot...Please suggest it for DB2 if possible..now i m working on DB2....and getting error                                       Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;1|Y-%m-20') - INTERVAL|<space>, DRIVER=3.59.81

Comment: What error please specify

Comment: i have already specified its                                      Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;1|Y-%m-20') - INTERVAL|<space>, DRIVER=3.59.81

Comment: deepika I tried its not working...have u got solution??

Comment: actually this query is according to SQL you are working on DB2, the syntax are different there, I don't have a workspace on DB2, and I can't suggest a query without checking its result

Comment: You can take help of DB2 manual at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html

Comment: anyways u gave me some idea...thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
  your_table 
WHERE 
  `CREATED_DATE` BETWEEN "2013-10-20" AND "2013-11-20";
```

Comment: yes..but its hard coded cant  "2013-10-20" AND "2013-11-20" be generic

Comment: and offcourse i know to do it by java but dont know how to do it by mysql